# startActivityForResult with google play games intent returning to wrong activity

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin, google-play-games

When I'm using startActivityForResult for anything from the google play games library (select players, leaderboard, achievements), and that activity returns, it returns to the phone's OS screen.  This was not happening to me at all before but now it does happen **only when a debugger is not attached**

I'm using xamarin so hence the C# code below:

```
StartActivityForResult(GamesClass.Achievements.GetAchievementsIntent(mGoogleApiClient),
                    REQUEST_ACHIEVEMENTS);
```

...

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode,
                             Intent intent)
    {
        //This does not get hit
        Logger.Debug(TAG, "OnActivityResult()");
    }
```

What the?

Answer (score 1):

Try starting you own activity for result, is the behavior the same?

Check if the activity from where you're trying to start is not declared as noHistory=true (and is not launched via an intent with this flag).

Comment: Haven't had a chance to check this yet but I will.